# Encrypting binary data (mp3) with PHP's openssl_public_encrypt

Tags: php, openssl, mp3, public-key-encryption

I am trying to use PHP's OpenSSL implementation to encrypt an MP3:

```
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

$mp3 = file_get_contents("/var/www/temp/audio.mp3");    
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
openssl_pkey_export($res, $private_key);
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$public_key = $public_key["key"];
openssl_public_encrypt($mp3, $encryptedmp3, $public_key);
file_put_contents("/var/www/temp/encryptedMp3",$encryptedmp3)
```

This generates no error, but the "encryptedMp3" file is empty.
Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong, and if there is another way to encrypt mp3s (and other binary data) with PHP and public/private key encryption?

Comment: Surely you'd want to use symmetric encryption on the whole file?  (You can encrypt the symmetric key asymmetrically if you want.)  What is your end goal?

Comment: @Brad The end goal is to be able to say to the users "your data is securely encrypted and nobody without this private key can access it - not even us"

Comment: As @Brad suggested, you can't use RSA to encrypt large amounts of data without creating your own block-oriented protocol, and even then you shouldn't. Instead, use a hybrid encryption technique where the data is encrypted with AES and the AES key is encrypted with RSA using OAEP padding.